# List of executed Stored Procedures and supplied parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to query a list of stored procedures together with the parameters supplied to them? I found some query but it did not returns the supplied parameters. I just want to know if that's possible. Or I need to create some scripts for this kind of logging?

BTW, I am using SQL Server.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the following

```
SELECT *
FROM   sys.procedures pr
inner join  sys.parameters p
                  on  p.object_id = pr.object_id
```

You can add and `name = 'MyProcName'`

If you want to get the last execution also: then use the following:

```
    SELECT  last_execution_time, *  
FROM   sys.procedures pr
inner join  sys.parameters p
                  on  p.object_id = pr.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.objects b 
               ON pr.object_id = b.object_id 
left join  sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats a
                  on  a.object_id = pr.object_id
```

Comment: I guess it worked fine. I just need to look for columns that I need. Thanks @Adel. BTW, precision in that table means the number of times it is executed? Am I right? And is it possible to add date executed?

Comment: Is it possible to add date executed? And parameters value?

Comment: Yes you can get the last exection from the following query: SELECT  last_execution_time, *  
FROM   sys.procedures pr
inner join  sys.parameters p
                  on  p.object_id = pr.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.objects b 
               ON pr.object_id = b.object_id 
left join  sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats a
      on  a.object_id = pr.object_id

Comment: I don't know but it shows Invalid object name 'sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats' on my side. Is it because of SQL Version?

Comment: Yes, this is because the view sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats was introduced from SQL Server 2008 onwards.

Comment: I see. I got the 2005 version.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
SELECT      SYSOBJ.NAME AS SP_NAME,
            PARAMS.NAME AS PARAMNAME
FROM        SYS.OBJECTS AS SYSOBJ
INNER JOIN  SYS.PARAMETERS AS PARAMS ON SYSOBJ.OBJECT_ID = PARAMS.OBJECT_ID
WHERE       SYSOBJ.TYPE='P'
```